# Что такое двоеточие в PHP или в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот такой код в WordPress:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Что делает двоеточие?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php три секунды гугла

Answer (score 4, accepted):

традиционно смотрим в [книгу](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

> PHP предлагает альтернативный синтаксис для некоторых его управляющих структур, а именно: `if`, `while`, `for`, `foreach` и `switch`. В каждом случае основной формой альтернативного синтаксиса является изменение открывающей фигурной скобки на двоеточие `:`, а закрывающей скобки на `endif;`, `endwhile;`, `endfor;`, `endforeach;` или `endswitch;` соответственно.

непосредственно [про `while`](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.while.php)

> Также, как и с оператором `if`, вы можете группировать несколько выражений внутри одного цикла `while`, заключая эти выражения между фигурными скобками или используя альтернативный синтаксис:

```
while (expr):
    statement
    ...
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

> что делает двоеточие?

Тоже, что и фигурные скобки.
[Матчасть](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

> В каждом случае основной формой альтернативного синтаксиса является
>   изменение открывающей фигурной скобки на двоеточие (:), а закрывающей
>   скобки на endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach; или endswitch;
>   соответственно.